# invalid factor level, NA generated when I try to add row to dataframe with var1 and Freq

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have a data frame, the head of which is:

```
head(loss_freq_table)
   Var1 Freq
1 1101   19
2 1102   18
3 1103   12
4 1104   19
5 1105   16
6 1106   12
```

However, when I type `loss_by_team<-rbind(loss_by_team, data.frame(Var1=1455, Freq=0))`, I get the error

```
Warning message:
 In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = 1455) :
   invalid factor level, NA generated
```

and when I type `loss_by_team[which(loss_by_team$Var1=="1455"), ]`, I get

```
[1] Var1 Freq
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

anyone know why this is?

Comment: Presumably, you constructed `loss_freq_table` with the `table` command? If so, you should use `table(factor(x,level=1101:2000))` or whatever levels you want to show up in the table up front, instead of trying to patch them in after the fact.

Comment: no, `loss_freq_table` is `loss_freq_table <- as.data.frame(table(season$lteam))`

Comment: It may be possible that the `var1` is `factor`.  You can convert it to 'character' and then `rbind`

Comment: Create your data.frame with `as.data.frame( table( season$lteam ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE )` and it should work.

Comment: Sure, the `as.data.frame` doesn't make any difference. The point is that the `table` command needs to know all the levels you want displayed ahead of time. To do this, convert to `factor` and tell it the levels. `table` converts to factor anyways. Anyway, this is just the standard way to approach the problem. As akrun said, you can convert to character and paste it on after-the-fact if you want to.